# How to Compare BCRYPT Hashed Passwords in PHP

Tags: php, hash, passwords, password-protection

I have a "create new user" form in HTML and need to know where certain parts of it need validating and checking (PHP or javascript) and the best way to go about it.

The password handling is done in PHP and so is the code that checks to see if the given username is available or already exists in the database. Need to know the best place to compare the "password" and "confirm password" fields as it seems hard to do when both are hashed in PHP.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { // If the form is submitted and by the method of post
    $new_username = test_input($_POST['new_username']); // Set new_username to the new_username value from the form
    $new_password = password_hash(test_input($_POST['new_password']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Get the new_password from the form and hash it before passing to the variable
    $confirm_password = password_hash(test_input($_POST['new_password_confirm']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Get the confirm_password field from the form and hash it
    $team = $_POST['new_team']; // Get the new_team field (doesn't need validation as it is a dropdown choice)
    $username_valid = test_account_validity($newConnection, $new_username);
    if ($username_valid) {
        echo "";
    }
    if (hash_equals($new_password, $confirm_password)) {
        echo "Passwords Match";
    }
    else {
        echo "Passwords Dont Match";
    }
}

function test_input($data) { // Function to remove spaces, slashes and special html characters before returning the valid data
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Expected Passwords match output when the passwords are the same before hashing (same entered into both form fields) but it says the passwords don't match.

***EDIT***

Different from how to use password hash as this is about comparing hashes with one another for two entered passwords rather than comparing a string to a hash or hashing to store in a database.

Comment: That's not what [`hash_equals`](http://php.net/hash_equals) does. Would it be helpful to link a basic introduction of password hashing again?

Comment: @mario if you have one that would really help, think I've just got it a bit confused. Thanks

Comment: Whey not simply compare the passwords and hash them after if they match? Also you should not edit the users password. If there are unallowed characters better notify the user about an invalid password instead of changing it.

Comment: @ich5003 Wouldn't that leave it open to a timing error. In that case do i still use hash_equals

Comment: I would use the following behavoiur: 1. Compare POST[pass] and POST[pass_verify], if they match, hash it and use it.
In your login method you would then use password_verify, because password_hash uses a salt, so hashing the same password two times does not create the same result. See here: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @ich5003 Thanks for the help, that was the method I was considering for the login, for comparing the post types, would I use hash_equals().

Comment: You should really think twice about the function `test_input`. Do you really need it? Do you know its purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use password\_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash)

Answer (score 2):

the scenario to login the user is

1. get the username and password from the html
2. get the user data that matches the username from the database
3. pass the plain password that came from user input and the hash from
   the database to `password_verify` function, if it returns true it
   means the password is correct otherwise the password is wrong

see the docs [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: That's fine for the login but i was more looking at password and confirm password fields to check they match

Comment: you confirm them before hashing if they are identical then you hash `POST['password']` and save it into the DB, `password_hash` function each time it generates hash it makes random string to put it in the equation which means it will generate different has each time you pass the `password` even if it was the same one

Comment: @FrankJance `hash_equals` compares two strings. When you generate hash using `password_hash` it uses random salt (random value) to randomize the hash result and prepend it to the hash to protect against dictionary attacks.  To verify the password hash again, you need to use the old salt from the hash and then use the same hash iterations count to verify if the new hash belongs to same value or not. `password_verify` does all of this work. Otherwise you need to do it yourself.